# How can I compile a tex with Helvetica under Linux?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, linux

I'm trying compiling [this latex template example](http://manas.tungare.name/software/latex/chi-extended-abstracts-template.zip) (CHI Extended Abstracts template) under linux (XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010/Arch Linux) using xelatex.

This is the output I'm getting: http://sprunge.us/YaXi

It seems that it's having troubles finding Helvetica, but helvetica is installed:
fc-list http://sprunge.us/GChE

Can you guys help?

**UPDATE:**
Trying to simplify the issue, I've been suggested on #latex to try with a simpler example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}


\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Which fails just as the template above. See http://sprunge.us/GJdG

Comment: You also have Nimbus Sans L installed, which is nearly identical to Helvetica. You could try that. Also, you shouldn't use babel with xelatex, but Polyglossia instead. (Though I've noticed that causes problems for blindtext.) But I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: Try this: \setmainfont{Helvetica Regular} Let me know the result.

Comment: Yeah, using Nimbus Sans L worked just fine.

Comment: @frabjous: We have TeX Gyre Heros now, please don't use the inferior GhostScript fonts anymore.

Comment: Check the type of the Helvetica fonts you have (`fc-list -v Helvetica | grep fontformat`). At least here, Helvetica is in [PCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Compiled_Format), a bitmap font format, which can't be used with Xe(La)TeX, even if listed by `fc-list`. On how to filter `fc-list`, and on what may be the same issue, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/terminus-with-fontspec-in-xetex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your Helvetica font is not properly installed. `fontspec` easily chokes on fonts that are duplicated for example (two different files providing the same font).

Check your installation.

Also, if you're not picky on the exact font to use, @frabjous' suggestion to use Nimbus Sans L (a free Helvetica clone) is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the case.. don't know how can I fix this though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

should work. It's worked for me

Comment: `\usepackage{tgheros}` please.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Why?