# Terminus with fontspec in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

When using `\setmonofont` with fontspec in XeTeX, I wonder what fonts (or type faces) I can use.

`fc-list` yields among others:

```
Terminus:style=Bold
Terminus:style=Regular
```

So I tried this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Terminus}
[...]
\testtt{monospace text}
```

I get the error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Terminus" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Now, which fonts *can* I use?

Is there a way to list them, or something? Incidentally, is there a way how I could use Terminus in XeTeX for monospaced text?

Comment: Operating system? TeX distribution? Location of Teriminus in the file system? Font Type (.otf?)?

Comment: Linux, installed font from repos. Font is not available as OpenType font, but appears in `fc-list`, so fontconfig does see it. I'm using XeTeX, and the fact that I use tools such as fc-list, makes it somewhat clear, that I use Linux. For reference, the font is located in `/usr/share/fonts/terminus`, and is a gziped X11 bitmap format (`.pcf.gz`).

Comment: `fontspec` is used for OpenType and TrueType fonts, so no, you can't use a bitmap version of Terminus with it.

Comment: OK, and how can I list available fonts then?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-ttf-fonts-with-xetex suggests to use `fc-list`, but apparently that also prints legacy fonts.

Comment: Not sure if this is entirely correct, but `fc-list -f "%{family} (%{fontformat})\n" | sort --unique | grep --color=never TrueType` might help.

Comment: Simpler: `fc-list :fontformat=TrueType`.

Comment: @Caramdir: OK, all fonts listed there are usable. Don't know if that's all of them or just a subset. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Caramdir: this won't print CFF (.otf) and Type 1 fonts and both can be used by XeTeX/LuaTeX. `fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"` should avoid listing bitmap only fonts (but I don't have such fonts to test).

Comment: There is a TTF version of the font [here](http://misc.nybergh.net/pub/fonts/terminus/ttf/).

Comment: @Khaled Hosny: The font I tried to use in the first place, Terminus, doesn't show up, so I guess it works. Thanks! The TTF version is quite poor, though. I decided to use another monospace font.

Comment: @Khaled You should add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitmap fonts are not supported by XeTeX/LuaTeX. To list outline fonts only, try:

```
fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"
```

There is also a [TTF version](http://misc.nybergh.net/pub/fonts/terminus/ttf/) of Terminus, though it seems outdated.

Comment: The command is what I was looking for, many thanks! The TTF version of Terminus isn't looking too good in print, I'll see if someone ever makes an OpenType version of it...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

```
fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n" | sort -u
```

It will sort them and removes duplicates out of the list.